# Permalinks not working on nginx centos 7

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, centos7

I have installed a vps on centos 7 with nginx, php-fpm, phpmyadmin, mariadb. I have setup a domain then installed 2 WordPress in two different folders like `/enter` and `/gallery`.

When I change permalinks from default to anything else, the posts and pages don't work. It shows 404 error. I deactivated all plugins, then set permalinks to post name, then edited the config file, saved and restart nginx. It's still not working.

Here is my nginx server block. I need to change it to make the site SEO friendly.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain.com [url]www.domain.com;[/url]
    root   /var/www/domain.com/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    error_page 404 /index.php;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /var/www/domain.com/html;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `root` is set as `/var/www/domain.com/html`, but you mention you have two different wordpress installs running. You will need to make sure you have the proper document root set for each of those directories as well as any rewrite rules that they require. The question is too broad to provide any useful answer otherwise. Please try narrowing it down further form there and repost a more elaborate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty permalinks need to handled by the `index.php` script of the appropriate WordPress install. You are currently redirecting everything to the URI `/index.php`, and from your question, it seems like `/var/www/domain.com/html/index.php` does not exist.

If you have two separate installations of WordPress, under `/enter` and `/gallery` you need to define locations for each with a default script for each:

```
location /enter {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /enter/index.php;
}
location /gallery {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /gallery/index.php;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much RIchard Smith. You save my day.its working for permalinks and also 404 error page redirect to index page. thanks